# Scraping tiingo HTML with Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tiingo

I am looking to scrape financial data for various companies in the S&P 500 from their respective webpages on tiingo.com

For example, take the following URL:

https://www.tiingo.com/f/b/aapl

which displays the most recent balance sheet data for Apple

I am looking to extract the "Property, Plant & Equipment" amount for the most recent quarter, which is 25.45B in this particular instance.  However, I'm having trouble writing the correct Beautiful Soup code to extract this text.

Inspecting the element, I see that the 25.45B number is within a class "ng-binding ng-scope" within an  element and within the class "col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 statement-field-data ng-scope," which itself is within the class "col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9 no-padding-left no-padding-right."

However, I'm not sure how to accurately write the Beautiful Soup code to locate the correct element and then execute the element.getText() function.

I was thinking something like this:

```
import os, bs4, requests

res_bal = requests.get("https://www.tiingo.com/f/b/aapl")

res_bal.raise_for_status()

soup_bal = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res_bal.text, "html.parser")

elems_bal = soup_bal.select(".col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 statement-field-data ng-scope")

elems_bal_2 = elems_bal.select(".ng-binding ng-scope")

joe = elems_bal_2.getText()

print(joe)
```

but so far I have not had success with this code.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The content is loaded using Javascript so not in the source you get back

Comment: Also `soup_bal.select(".col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 statement-field-data ng-scope")` is not even remotely close to being correct. You might need to read the docs https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I'm the founder of Tiingo and this scraping violates the terms. Just pay for a personal license from quandl.com/sf1 for $50/month. The founder of of Sharadar is a good person and works very hard to keep this dataset clean.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem with your selectors

```
elems_bal = soup_bal.select(".col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 statement-field-data ng-scope")

elems_bal_2 = elems_bal.select(".ng-binding ng-scope")
```

is that, there are multiple elements present of the page with same class and therefore your are not getting correct results.

Note if you use only beautifulsoup  and request then the content in the page source does not have data which you want to scrape and this can be done
with the help of selenium and beautifulsoup you can do it: if you do not have selenium install first do: `pip install selenium`

here is working code for the same:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import  bs4, time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()   
driver.get("https://www.tiingo.com/f/b/aapl")
driver.maximize_window()
# sleep is given so that JS populate data in this time
time.sleep(10)
pSource= driver.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pSource, "html.parser")

Property=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 statement-field-name indent-2'})
for P in Property:
    if 'Property' in P.text.strip():
        print P.text

x=soup.find("a",{"ng-click":"toggleFundData('Property, Plant & Equipment',SDCol.restatedString==='restated',true)"})
print x.text
```

The output for the same is:

```
Property, Plant & Equipment
25.45B
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, thebadguy!!